# Add fonts to CKEditor (in Drupal)

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, truetype

I have downloaded three fonts - .tff files - from http://www.FontIneed.com and installed them under Linux. They are really installed throughout the system because they are now present in the OpenOffice suite fonts drop down boxes.
As I have installed CKEditor as rich text editor in Drupal, I have tried to add these fonts to it.
I already had a problem when testing in Drupal->Config->CKEditor->Advanced if the Javascript insertion works for a given profile. I entered exactly the example that is provided under the texfield box but, when created a new block in Full HTML, the fonts drop-down list presented the whole set of available fonts (not only the ones I have entered).
Then, I wanted to add my new fonts to the CKEDITOR.config.font_names in the plugin.js file (although I don't like that because it will blow-up my setting when new release will overwrite this file ...). But the new fonts don't show up.
What should I do?
Thanks
PS: I may have a problem entering their names. For example, I've got one font with the Zipty_Do.tff file; the first line of the file says 'Zipty Do, Regular' and that's the name I've entered

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of wether you are able to get your new fonds to show up in CkEditor, I believe that if you have installed a free font, chances are that they are not standard system fonts. Without embedding the fonts on the site itself these fonts will only be available to you and will thus show up different to visitors of your site.

A module I found extremely helpful in embedding non system fonts is Cufon http://drupal.org/project/cufon. Hope this helps.